# Formants in Praat Exercises

Tags: vowels, praat, formants

How do I measure formants in a Praat graph or diagram? is there any way to calcualate formant frequency?

Answer (score 3):

Having selected a sound object, you look at it via the view and edit button in the Objects window. Select the Formant tab and make the first entry, Show Formants, be checked. You then have to select a small enough stretch (mouse select) and zoom in (^n) so that a spectrogram appears. Otherwise you'll see a blank window telling you about the maximum length of an analysis window). Then there are two settings tabs, which almost surely you don't need to mess with. To get specific numeric values, select a span of interest and press F1 for first formant, F2 for second formant and so on. Each of these will display the mean F1 (F2....) in the selection. You can also menu-select Formant Listing, which gives you F1-4 in evenly-spaced windows, along with the time corresponding to those red dots.